# How to increase Chakra-UI Tabs/ TabsPanel width?

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

Chakra-UI's `<Tabs />` and `<TabPanels />` minimizes the with of the content within, thus throwing off the layout. This is a screenshot of the layout I'm using. I've removed the data and added colors to the `<Cards />` so you can better visualize what I'm referring to.

[image]

I am using a custom `Card`, see

```
    <Box
      w={"full"}
      color={color || ""}
      bg={useColorModeValue(bg, bg) || useColorModeValue("white", "white")}
      boxShadow={"1xl"}
      rounded={"md"}
      overflow={"hidden"}
    >
      <Stack textAlign={"left"} p={6} align={"left"}>
        {props.children}
      </Stack>
    </Box>
```

How can I increase the width of the card colored in cyan using CSS so the better align with the others? Should the styling be applied to the `TabPanel />` itself of the `<Card />`

***A partial solution***

I've come across this particular CSS code that I mostly use in my Bootstrap projects which basically allows me to break out of a container and set the width to full size of the screen, but this would make the `<Card />` wider than the others.

```
.break-container {
   width: 100vw !important;
   position: relative !important;
   left: calc(-1 * (100vw - 100%) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply adjust the horizontal padding of the TabPanel elements

```
  <TabPanels>
    <TabPanel px={0}>
      <p>one!</p>
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel px={0}>
      <p>two!</p>
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel px={0}>
      <p>three!</p>
    </TabPanel>
  </TabPanels>
```

You can also define it globally within the theme object:

```js
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Tabs: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: "soft-rounded"
      },
      variants: {
        "soft-rounded": {
          tabpanel: {
            px: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please try (sx) in your code to customize your cahkra-ui’s elements!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).